# Getting error on laravel 5 trying to encode an image

Tags: image, laravel, intervention

I installed "composer require intervention/image"... 
added on config/app.php

providers: Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class, 
aliases: 'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

then on my routes I have this:

```
Route::get('/thread/{img}', 'ThreadController@mostrarImagen');
```

on my ThreadController.php:

Imports:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Thread;
use App\Subboard;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

Function:

```
public function mostrarImagen($id) {
    $thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);
    $imagen = Image::make($thread->thrImg);
    $response = Response::make($thread->encode('jpeg'));
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    return $response;
}
```

getting this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::encode()
```

EDIT: got the example from this website http://www.core45.com/using-database-to-store-images-in-laravel-5-1/, is there something i'm missing?

Comment: why are you calling `encode` on your model?

Comment: ?? its a function inside my threadController i posted it :S

Comment: You are calling `encode` on your model. `$thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);` is a model. `$thread->encode('jpeg');` is calling `encode` on your model.

Comment: i ght the example from this website http://www.core45.com/using-database-to-store-images-in-laravel-5-1/ he does it on the controller too :S, it's not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, was encoding my class instead of the image, it was

$response = Response::make(**$imagen**->encode('jpeg'));